# How to avoid getting grid arrangements with plotROCCurves()?

Tags: r, roc, mlr

I want to plot ROC Curves into one plot, so that I can compare each one. An easy on going tutorial for that can be found on [MLR-org.com](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/roc_analysis.html).

There you found this example:

```
library(mlr)
n = getTaskSize(sonar.task)
train.set = sample(n, size = round(2/3 * n))
test.set = setdiff(seq_len(n), train.set)

lrn1 = makeLearner("classif.lda", predict.type = "prob")
mod1 = train(lrn1, sonar.task, subset = train.set)
pred1 = predict(mod1, task = sonar.task, subset = test.set)

lrn2 = makeLearner("classif.ksvm", predict.type = "prob")
mod2 = train(lrn2, sonar.task, subset = train.set)
pred2 = predict(mod2, task = sonar.task, subset = test.set)

df = generateThreshVsPerfData(list(lda = pred1, ksvm = pred2), measures = list(fpr, tpr))
plotROCCurves(df)
```

This should generate a graphic like this:

[image]

But instead I get always this one:

[image]

**Is anybody there who can help me to get only one graphic?**

Comment: With your provided script I get the upper plot. Try to install the latest version of mlr and start a fresh R session. Maybe you have another `plotROCCurves` function in your environment. If this does not lead to the desired result post a `sessionInfo()`

Comment: I've reinstalled everything and now it works. Thank you very much Jakob! I didn't thought that this might be the problem.